# Does mixing up GTK and Qt applications slow down the machine?

Tags: cpu, gtk, qt, benchmark

Usually it is recommended to either use `GTK` or `Qt` apps in the operating system, but not mixing them both together.

**Example:**

When using `KDE` it seems to be obvious to use `KMail` (`Qt`) instead of `Thunderbird` (`GTK`).

Or: When using `Gnome` it is recommended to use `Thunderbird` instead of `KMail`.

---

**My question is:** Are there any disadvantages in relation to CPU efficiency/task handling speed when mixing up both application types?

Comment: No, it absolutely doesn't matter. You can run multiple Gtk or Qt apps even on older machines, but  KDE or Gnome monsters + their respective ecosystems are each capable to bring a machine to its knees on their own ;-)

Comment: i agree that GTK vs QT doesn't matter.  It will be Gnome or KDE that brings the system to a crawl.

Comment: Related on Ask Ubuntu: [Is it bad to have Qt apps on a GTK environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/722324), which was asked and then closed in 2016--I wrote a long answer over there to demystify the issue; no benchmark to prove though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will use more RAM and cache, because of the extra libraries. This will cause a slow down (more swapping, if RAM is low; more cache misses). However you will probably not notice.